# How to convert database mysql4 to mysql5

Tags: mysql, migration

I have mysql dump file named `booster.dump`. It was export from `4.0.27-standard` mysql server. Now I want to convert this database to mysql `5.1.73-cll`. How can I do it? I search about this topic in internet and I have got a lots of solution but no one work for me.

Comment: So, what exactly did you try and what errors did you get? "no one work" is vague.

Comment: I try to emport my existing dump file to mysql5 and I got this error msg. ` You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'TYPE=MyISAM' at line 8`

Comment: You should change the `TYPE=` to `ENGINE=`

Comment: And I thought that `TYPE` was deprecated only in 5.1 and removed in 5.5 It should only give you a warning, not error.

Comment: Do you have 5.1.7 version?

Comment: In 5.1.7 it was removed, he says that he uses 5.1.73

Comment: @FloDoe MySQL docs indicate that in 5.1.7 the TYPE was removed and then reallowed (but still deprecated) again in 5.1.8. It was finally removed in 5.5

Comment: yes, thats true, was my fault that I didn´t wrote that it was reintroduced again for legacy support :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following on a Linux system:

`sed 's/TYPE=/ENGINE=/g' booster.dump > booster_sane.dump` and afterwards import the booster_sane.dump. If you don´t care about your original file you can also make the changes inplace before importing: `sed -i 's/TYPE=/ENGINE=/g'` (or specify a suffix to `-i` option to make a backup on the fly).

The reason for your error is explained in the comments to your question.